# wordpress jquery lightbox suddenly not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, lightbox, conflict

I'm using Jquery Lightbox plugin on Wordpress. I updated to Wordpress 3.6.1 and now the plugin not working. I already tried to disable the other plugins but nothing changed.. I still think it may be a jquery conflict or a problem with my theme. Someone told me that the solution is to comment out the jquery lines of my theme to run the local installation of Jquery, but I can't do that because of the jquery slider inside my theme. 
[This in the link to my site.](http://www.espoarte.net) Can anyone help me? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have already resolved the issue. I can see that lightbox is working fine